# Make code both 1.7 & 1.8 compatible?

Tags: java, compatibility, nashorn

We want to give our users the choice of using Java 1.7 or 1.8

Our application uses a JavaScript engine, which for 1.7 is Mozilla Rhino and for 1.8 is Oracle Nashorn. (yes, they replaced it and broke backward compatibility!)

In our JS-callable Java code, in order to use Nashorn, we must use the 1.8 class `jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.StaticClass`.

When using `StaticClass`, the code can't be compiled or run in Java 1.7 anymore. What would be the easiest solution to this?

Comment: Pay attention with `*.internal.*`: I just went to a conference and Mark Reinhold himself told that from `Java 9` they will be unusable (as well as `sun.*` packages). Probably some information here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/

Comment: The javadoc of `jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/NativeJava.java#type(Object, Object) ` literally states: `Given a name of a Java type, returns an object representing that type in Nashorn. The Java class of the objects used to represent Java types in Nashorn is not {@link java.lang.Class} but rather {@link StaticClass}.` I guess when we decide to support Java 9, the same compatibility issue will pop up again.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one class you need, write your own implementation that is  1.7 compatible.

As long as the fully qualified name is the same, the class loader doesn't care where it finds it.